# Call to NotifyAllocator fails when connection filter to InPlaceTransformFilter

Tags: c++, directshow

I get a : Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. in `DecideAllocator` method of my custom mux filter when trying to connect the filter to another custom written TransInPlaceFilter.

The filters:

[image: filters]

The first filter is derived from CBaseFilter. The second from CTransInPlaceFiler.

Connecting the mux filter to a avi mux filter works fine. The error could be in the transformer filter. However I am not sure where, because CTransInPlace filters do not use custom written pins but predefined pins.

The DecideAllocator function:

```
HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::DecideAllocator(IMemInputPin *pPin, IMemAllocator **ppAlloc)
{
    ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES *pprops = new ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES;
    HRESULT hr = pPin->GetAllocatorRequirements(pprops);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

        hr = InitAllocator(ppAlloc);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;

    hr = DecideBufferSize(*ppAlloc, pprops);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

-    hr = pPin->NotifyAllocator(*ppAlloc, TRUE); //error happens here

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    *ppAlloc = m_pAllocator;
    //m_pAllocator = *ppAlloc;

    m_pAllocator->Commit();
    m_pAllocator->AddRef();
    return hr;

}
```

The stack trace

```
qasf.dll!000007f8c5e5ec90() Unknown
qasf.dll!000007f8c5e611c9() Unknown
myfilter64.ax!MCMyOutputPin::DecideAllocator(IMemInputPin * pPin, IMemAllocator * * ppAlloc) Line 193   C++
myfilter64.ax!MCMyOutputPin::CompleteConnect(IPin * pReceivePin) Line 58    C++
myfilter64.ax!CBasePin::AttemptConnection(IPin * pReceivePin, const CMediaType * pmt) Line 1799 C++
myfilter64.ax!CBasePin::TryMediaTypes(IPin * pReceivePin, const CMediaType * pmt, IEnumMediaTypes * pEnum) Line 1890    C++
myfilter64.ax!CBasePin::AgreeMediaType(IPin * pReceivePin, const CMediaType * pmt) Line 1956    C++
myfilter64.ax!CBasePin::Connect(IPin * pReceivePin, const _AMMediaType * pmt) Line 1728 C++
[External Code] 
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a90206e()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a899ee1()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a8a519d()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a6543c2()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a656084()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a65011b()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a650c04()    Unknown
[External Code] 
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a667ad6()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a66811e()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a803eed()    Unknown
GraphStudioNext64.exe!000007f63a7e4c6c()    Unknown
[External Code]
```

Comment: Check your pointer addresses before dereferencing.

Comment: Using your debugger, single step until the pointers are dereferenced and look at the pointer values.